# One of three files cannot be downloaded in one session (python-requests)

Tags: python, python-requests

I am new to python and coding in general, so please forgive me any inaccuracy.

I am trying to automate daily data download from my contractor's website, but only two of three files can download correctly. The third one instead of target data contains... a html code of that website... But when I copy the url of that "strange" file from my code and paste it to my browser's address bar I can download this file efficiently, so I think this is not about wrong url. Could this be due to the size of this file? The two, which are ok are small (about 95 and 230 KB), but that one, that I cannot download is about 4,5 MB. What I am doing wrong? Any help will be appreciate.

Here is my code. (That "bad" file is `price.xlsx`)

```
import requests, os
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
avail = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S") + '_avail.csv'
price = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S") + '_price.xlsx'
logo = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S") + '_logo.zip'
site_url = 'https://www.somewebsi.te/login/'
payload = {'login':'myLogin', 'pass': 'myPassword'}
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
avail_url = 'https://www.somewebsi.te/avail.csv'
price_url = 'https://www.somewebsi.te/price.xlsx'
logo_url = 'https://www.somewebsi.te/logo.zip'

b = requests.Session()
b.get(site_url)
b.post(site_url, headers=headers, data=payload)

r = b.get(avail_url)
q = b.get(price_url)
t = b.get(logo_url)

with open(avail, 'wb') as output:
    output.write(r.content)
size = os.stat(avail)
print(f"File {avail} downloaded successfully! {size.st_size} bytes.")

with open(price, 'wb') as output:
    output.write(q.content)
size = os.stat(price)
print(f"File {price} downloaded successfully! {size.st_size} bytes.")

with open(logo, 'wb') as output:
    output.write(t.content)
size = os.stat(logo)
print(f"File {logo} downloaded successfully! {size.st_size} bytes.")

b.close()
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'cannot download'? please be specific about the behavior you observe.

Comment: It may be caused by you contractor's server behavior. Maybe you have to provide some additional headers or something like that. Maybe this returned HTML code gives some answers. Also, you could take a closer look at response code and headers.

Comment: This script saves three files on my disk. One of them named "..price.xlsx" contains a html code of main website that I am logged in. I don't know why. When I am trying to download this file "manually" by clicking link (or pasting `https://www.somewebsi.te/price.xlsx` into address bar) browser starts downloading correct file which contains data that I need (some product details).